# Cannot connect to Sybase database, additional arguments necessary?

Tags: r, odbc, sybase, r-dbi

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase database (ASE) using the `DBI` and `odbc` packages. Using these packages the connection fails. However, when using the same dsn and the `RODBC` package, the connection does work. What are possible causes of the failure using `DBI` and `odbc`? Should I provide additional arguments when connecting to a Sybase server? (See below)

**Reproducible example**

```
# Attempt 1 using DBI and odbc fails
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  dsn  = myDsn,
  UID  = myLogin,
  PWD  = myPassword,
  Port = port
)

# Attempt 2 using RODBC succeeds
library(RODBC)

con2 <- odbcConnect(
  dsn = myDsn,
  uid = myLogin, 
  pwd = myPassword,
  believeNRows = FALSE
)
```

**The error received when using DBI / odbc**

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 08S01: [DataDirect][ODBC OpenAccess SDK driver][OpenAccess SDK Client]TCP/IP error, connection timed out
```

**My questions**

- Should I provide additional arguments when calling dbConnect to connect to a Sybase server?
- If so, which ones?
- If not, what else am I doing wrong? (The dsn works as shown using the `RODBC` package.)

I've tried to look up extra info [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive/), which seems to suggest I may need extra arguments. But my knowledge in this field is limited, so I'm not sure how to adapt it to the current situation.

**Sybase database version**

Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7

**Session info**

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  tools     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-15 DBI_0.7      odbc_1.1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12     compiler_3.4.2 hms_0.3        tibble_1.3.4   Rcpp_0.12.13   bit64_0.9-7    blob_1.1.0     rlang_0.1.2
```